# How to replace a watch face's hand vectors in Wear OS?

Tags: image, kotlin, wear-os

How do I remap the watch hands to a vector/how do I change the shape of the hands? I have a drawable vector resource I want to use as the hand, but I don't know how to replace the drawn line to use a vector.

I found this picture on the Android developers website:

[image: what I want]

I don't care about the complications in the face. I don't need those. I just want the hands to use a vector resource, and not be just a line.
What I have, but I don't want is similar to this:

[image: what I have]

Comment: Look into `Canvas.rotate()` and `.drawBitmap()`. With those two methods, your `onDraw` code almost writes itself.

Comment: @String I don't completely understand it. It is unclear to me what syntax I should use. Also, is your comment still relevant after the edit?

Comment: Since you changed the question, my previous comment doesn't completely cover it any more. But asking how to "modify the shape" is far too vague to answer: there are **many** ways that a shape could be modified. Maybe post some code - including your vector source? - so that we can see what you're really working with. And describe specifically how you want to "modify" it.

Comment: No. I don't want to modify a shape or a vector. I want to use a vector as the watch hand.

Comment: Well, the first sentence of your question says "modify the shape", maybe that's why I thought you wanted to, er, *modify the shape*.  If you just want to use a vector drawable without modification, what's wrong with the `Drawable.draw(canvas)` method?

Comment: There is no such method as `Drawable.draw`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWGbC.png
Welp...

Comment: Um, yeah, it's not a static method. You need to instantiate your vector drawable first, then call `draw()` on that. Seriously, this is pretty basic stuff.